# python, write the contents of a list to a text file

Tags: python, list, writetofile

I created a program in python that is used to create/edit user generated lists. I tried to create a save function that will save a list to a text file, but I'm having a problem. It will create the text file but not write the content of the list to the text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
user_list = []
def banner():
    logo = open('chlogo2', 'r')
    for line in logo:
        print line.strip('\n')
    logo.close
    main(user_list)
def save(user_list):
    print "\nENTER A SAVE NAME.\nTHIS WILL BE SAVED AS A .TXT FILE.\n"
    w = ("saves/" + raw_input("CNG>SAVE NAME> ") +".txt")
    wr = open(w, 'w')
    for i in user_list:
        i.write(user_list, '\n')
    main(user_list)
def prt(user_list):
    print '\nCURRENT LIST -\n'
    r = user_list
    for line in r:
        print line.strip('\n')
    main(user_list)
def add(user_list):
    print "\nTYPE AN ENTRY IN A 'POSITION' then 'ENTRY' FORMAT\nPRESS 'ENTER' WITHOUT AN INPUT TO RETURN TO THE MAIN FUNTION\n"
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("CNG>ADD>P> "))
        y = raw_input("CNG>ADD>E> ")
        x -= 1
        user_list.insert(x, y)
        add(user_list)
    except:
        main(user_list)
def main(user_list):    
    option = open('options')
    for line in option:
        print line.strip('\n')
    option.close
    opt = raw_input("CHG> ")


    if opt == "list":
        prt(user_list)
    elif opt == 'banner':
        banner()
    elif opt == 'exit':
        print ' '
    elif opt == 'empty':
        user_list = []
    elif opt == 'add':
        add(user_list)
    elif opt == 'save':
        save(user_list)     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    banner()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line:

`for i in user_list:
     i.write(user_list, '\n')`

Change it to this:

```
for i in user_list:
    wr.write(i, '\n')
```

**EDIT:** And remove `user_list` parameter from all of your functions because it is a global variable and you can access it from within your any function. This may also be a reason why your list not getting saved.

Comment: Actually it should be `wr.write(i, '\n')`.

Comment: Thanks @EngineerCamp, I have fixed it.

Comment: It still is not working. It's still only creating the file and not writing the list's content to it.

Comment: Maybe your `user_list` is empty. Is there anything in it?
Try to check it's contents in your `save` function before saving it.

Comment: Yes. I'll add values to the list but they won't show up on the text file.

Comment: Try to remove `user_list` parameter from your functions. Write it as for example `def save(): # statements`

Comment: Also, you need to correctly close your files. `option.close` doesn't do anything, you need to *call*  the method `option.close()` (you're not doing either with the file you're writing to where it's even more important). Even better, use a [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: `write` only take 1 argument, so it should be `wr.write(i + '\n')`